# Making A ROT13 through strings in Python

Tags: python, loops, rot13

I have searched for this question and found some ways to do this. Some solutions were in one line too. There was one solution in which the data is stored in list and then the method append is used to make a word.
The other methods are working .
Though I want to know what is wrong with my code.
EDIT 1 : The problem with my code is that is shows only the first alphabet  of the input string in the output instead of the whole word.
here is my code :

```
alph = {"a":"n" , "b":"o" ,"c":"p" , "d":"q","e":"r" , "f":"s" , "g":"t" ,"h":"u" , "i":"v",  "j":"w", "k":"x" , "l":"y" , "m":"z" ,"n":"a", "o": "b" ,  "p":"c" ,"q":"d" ,"r":"e" ,"s":"f", "t":"g" ,"u":"h", "v":"i", "w":"j", "x":"k", "y":"l", "z":"m" }
def rot(word):
    rt = ''
    for c in word:
        if c.islower():
            rt += alph.get(c)
            return rt
        if c.isupper():
            c = c.lower()
            rt += alph.get(c).capitalize()
            return rt
        if c not in alph:
            rt += c
            return rt

word = raw_input("Enter:")
print rot(word)
```

Please check and tell me what is wrong in it.

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with it? You tried it with some input and got the wrong output or an error?

Comment: Side-note: ROT13 in Python can be implemented with a one-time call to `string.maketrans` (Py2)/`str.maketrans` (Py3) and then using the result to call `str.translate`. No need for explicit loops at all.

Comment: Ryan , the output comes as a single first alphabet of the input string  instead of the whole word.

Comment: Ok shadowranger, I will check the one you mentioned right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, a more elegant way to do this is to use python's built-in string `translate` methods to avoid writing the loop by hand but if you have to write your own loop:

The reason your output comes back as only the first letter is that you return from each of your `if` statements in the `for` loop. This means that on the first iteration of the loop, the first character is translated, added to the `rt` string, and immediately returned from the function; the rest of the string is never translated.

To fix this, simply remove the `return rt` from the bottom of each `if` statement, and put a single `return rt` after the loop and at the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation  . I changed it and now its working.